# Injecting a stateful repository into a WorkManager Worker

Tags: android, dagger-2, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

This is mostly an app architecture question.
I have a repository class that centralizes operations on collections of media:

```
interface MediaRepository {
    suspend fun getTracks(): List<Track>
    suspend fun getAlbums(): List<Album>
    fun observeMediaChanges(): Flow<ChangeNotification>
}
```

This repository pulls from multiple DAOs sources that expose their data as `Flow` to observe for changes like the following:

```
interface MediaDao {
    fun getTracks(): Flow<List<Track>>
    fun getAlbums(): Flow<List<Album>>
}
```

Therefore, the implementation of `MediaRepository` is stateful: it lazily observes changes to the `Flow`s from the first time the equivalent `getX` function is called, caches the latest received value whenever received then compute and broadcasts a `ChangeNotification` to observers of `observeMediaChanges()`.

This structure worked well when the `Repository` was only injected into a `Service`, because the repository resources could be cleaned-up when the service terminated. I now need to inject the same `MediaRepository` into an instance of `Worker`. Since workers have their own lifecycle, I need to make the `MediaRepository` a singleton.

#### The problem

by keeping active subscriptions for the whole lifetime of the application, am I leaking valuable resources (for example, one DAO internally uses `ContentObserver`s) ?
How can I change my app architecture to avoid leaks ?

#### What I thought of

1. Make `MediaRepository` stateless and expose media lists as `Flow`s. It is then the consumer's reponsibility to cache the latest value.
2. Keep the cache in `MediaRepository`, but do not share instances between the service and the worker.
3. Do not use a cache at all, since most data are read from the device's storage.

Comment: Your Repository shouldn't be stateful. Solved!

Comment: I've considered that. Then where should I introduce a cache layer in this case ? SInce caches are always stateful

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have already a dagger component declared.

You only mark the provided MediaRepository implementation with @Singleton.

```
@Singleton
class MediaRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(...)
```

And in a module bind this instance to its interface

```
@Binds fun bindsMediaRepository(impl: MediaRepositoryImpl): MediaRepository
```

To give additional parameters to a Worker you have to instantiate a custom WorkManagerFactory in your application.

[This medium post](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-setup-with-workmanager-a-complete-step-by-step-guild-bb9f474bde37) explains the full process step by step very detailed.

Take also a look to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've had a rather a rather precise idea of how to setup those factories. The problem I have is that exposing my repository as a singleton has a high risk of leaking memory because it is stateful. I'm looking for a way to structure my application to avoid that

Comment: Then as EpicPandaForce point out, this should not be `@Singleton`. Anyway if you are forced to, you can reuse a current created instance marking it as `@Reusable` instead, This way dagger will free the instance if any consumer is not longer pointing to it.